# Jetstream UI opciones de menú

Tags: laravel-jetstream

Estoy instalando laravel con las opciones de jetstream pero trase seguir todos los paso en el menú únicamente aparece la opción de logout y no la de profile, igualmente, si me dirijo a user/profile me sale una página en blanco.

Estos son los pasos que sigo:

- composer create-project laravel/laravel proyecto
- composer require laravel/jetstream
- php artisan jetstream:install livewire --teams
- npm install && npm run dev
- aquí creo la BBDD -
- php artisan migrate
- composer require laravel/ui
- php artisan ui bootstrap --auth

Y aparentemente todo es correcto, sin errores pero no consigo tener las opciones nativas de jetstream, ni siquiera la página del Dashboard. Estoy con Laravel 9. Any idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Pues parece que es al añadir las vistas en Bootstrap, tanto en Laravel 8 como en Laravel 9 :(

Comment: Solventado con la reinstalación de Jetstream